# Gatsby open modal window on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, gatsby

I'm working on a website about donation using Gatsby v2 (Reactjs) and I need an example like open modal window on button donation click using Gatsby or ReactJS. I search on internet and I got nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the react-modal package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple (Gatsby) page that makes use of [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) as an example. In this example I've replaced the default IndexPage in the Gatsby v2's new starter site that you can generate via the CLI.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactModal from 'react-modal'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'

import Layout from '../components/layout'

ReactModal.setAppElement('#main')

class IndexPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isModalOpen: false,
    }
  }
  handleModalOpen = event => {
    // console.log('handleModalOpen: ', event);
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: true })
  }

  handleModalClose = event => {
    // console.log('handleModalOpen: ', event);
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <div id="main">
          <h1>Hi people</h1>
          <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
          <p>Now go build something great.</p>

          <Link to="#" onClick={this.handleModalOpen}>
            Donate Now
          </Link>
        </div>
        <ReactModal
          isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
          onRequestClose={this.handleModalClose}
          contentLabel="Example Modal In Gatsby"
        >
          <h2>Donate</h2>
          <button onClick={this.handleModalClose}>Close Modal</button>
        </ReactModal>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default IndexPage
```

That should get you going. Best to read up on how to expand on this example [using react-modal here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) (or use an alternative).

Answer (score 2):

First of all the above example will not work because **#main** doesn't exist, right now the id for Gatsby app is **___gatsby**, so it shoul look like this

```
ReactModal.setAppElement('#___gatsby')
```

But it's not good to hope that this id is not going to change in the future. So it's better to implement your own React modal component, here is a good example https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-modal-component